# Setting margin-left to 0 using .css() not working

Tags: jquery

I don't know why this shouldn't work. It's an image slider but the problem seems to be that once all of the images have run out (current slide === slides.length) the slideshow doesn't restart by setting the margin-left back to 0. It just keeps going infinitely on. Thanks. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1291beag/

```
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

    setInterval(function() {
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-=' + width}, animationSpeed);
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
    }, pause);

});
```

Comment: Assuming your variables are in the state you expect them to be, this should work fine. Can you give an example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1291beag/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use !important to that element

For e.g.

```
 $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '0 !important');
```

This should work

Comment: nah still nothing. Thanks.